My NetBeans does not have the Hibernate configuration file wizard, how can I add this?
I downloaded Apache NetBeans 23, and Java 23. However, when I click on the projects tab/right click the source packages/new/other there is no Hibernate category for me to click to use the configuration file wizard.
It never contained hibernate in the Java Dependencies folder, I added it manually by adding the dependency to the pom.xml file and I have the Hibernate and Jakarta JARS in my dependencies folder.
I am able to import and use the Hibernate and Jakarta packages into my project code.
How can I add the configuration file wizard functionality?
I made the configuration file manually but it has not worked yet.
